# Is there a way to refactor all occurrences of a certain line at the same time in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut

I would like to refactor multiple occurrences of the same line at the same time, similar to the "F6" (I think) refactor option in Intelij IDEA.

From what I have found so far is by holding Alt + Shift and selecting multiple lines...

Comment: P.S. I am not sure how to "make" Alt, Shift and F6 look like keys if somebody would suggest that too would be useful for the future.

Comment: what makes me believe that it might have this option is that I can see that it sees other lines with the same code like the one I am highlighting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VScode has the option to refactor symbols, however, it depends on the current language server you are using (e.g. the language your files are written into and the support for that language offered by VScode or the extensions you have installed). For javascript/typescript, VScode has a native language server and you can use that immediately.

To use the refactoring options just highlight the piece of code you want to refactor (maybe a variable name) and from the command palette pick a refactoring option (e.g. `rename symbol` or `refactor`), you should then be prompted with the available refactors and you can, for example, change the name of the highlighted symbol. Of course, refactors will propagate your changes whenever it's convenient (changing names around, moving stuff, etc...).

Some other refactoring options are presented to you automatically when you perform specific actions, for example, if you move a file you are prompted to propagate the action and refactor all the imports of that file automatically.

You can find all the specific refactoring options in the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring).

If instead you just want to edit multiple lines there are lots of text-editing options, for example, you can alt+click (like you already found out) or you can highlight a portion of text and cmd+d/ctrl+d to highlight multiple instances of the same text with multiple cursors. You can find all text selection option in the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics) as well.

Comment: ok, I see your point, I think for what I am doing right now (small project-ish) ctrl + d is enough. Thank a lot.